# IOS/Objective-C/Storyboard: Detect when show segue underway

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using a standard "show" segue in storyboard for a transition between two view controllers.

In the second VC, there is a method in `viewWillAppear` that fires a progress bar that is appearing during the segue and marring its appearance.

Is there any way to detect that the segue is in progress so that I can delay the progress bar until after the segue is complete?

I know I could move the progress bar to a later point in the lifecycle of the second view controller such as `viewDidAppear` but in most cases, the VC is reached without this particular segue and I would like the progress bar to fire immediately.  If in the midst of the segue, however, I'd like to delay it.

Note: these are garden variety show Segues with animation in Storyboard, not custom segues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a public method for fire the progress bar and call it from first VC.
Here is the implementation of this approach: 
In `FirstVC.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // set segu identifier to SecondVC in StoryBoard        
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondVC"]) {
            SecondVC *secondVC = (SecondVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
            [secondVC fireProgressBar];
    }
}
```

In `SecondVC.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondVC : UIViewController
  -(void)fireProgressBar;
@end
```

In `SecondVC.m`:

```
#import "SecondVC.h"

@implementation SecondVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)fireProgressBar {
    NSLog(@"Progress Bar Fired!!!");
}

@end
```

Comment: I used a slight variation of this.  I put a boolean ivar in the second view controller _showProgress and set it to FALSE in prepareforsegue of the first and conditioned the method on the boolean.  Then I reset the boolean in viewdidappear of the second to TRUE.